# jQuery.post is being sent as HTTP GET on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 to call some backend server api's via jQuery's ajax POST. The backend server and the webpage are both on the same domain.

In my js file, I'm simply calling `$.post('/createAccount',data,function(e) { alert(e); });`

In Fiddler, this request is being sent as a GET, in IE9.

```
GET http://[redacted]/createAccount HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: [redacted]
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: [redacted]
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

The same page using Chrome (latest) returns the following in Fiddler:

```
POST http://[redacted]/createAccount HTTP/1.1
Host: [redacted]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 103
Origin: http://[redacted]
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://[redacted]/builder?token=[redacted]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

email=test123&token=[redacted]&company=tokentest1
```

Here is the code using $.ajax instead of $.post (same issue):

```
        $.ajax({
            url : '/createAccount',
            type : 'POST',
            data : obj,
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: 'false',
            success : function(data) {
                if(data.status === 'ok') {

                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: For debugging, can you switch to using $.ajax and compare the results?

Comment: I can (actually the original call was $.ajax({...,type:'POST'}). Is there any special benefit wrt debugging?

Comment: Well, since $.post forwards to $.ajax, it eliminates $.post as the cause.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help, but what if you set `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`? Same result? Try removing the `cache: 'false'` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a derp moment. I had some code else where that would fallback to MSFT's XDomainRequest, and in that code it was forcing all requests to get, instead of pulling the request type from the jQuery options object.